# Am I using these Switch statements correctly? I keep getting the same few names

Tags: java

I'm running into issues with a name generator I've been working on. And I'm curious if my problem is in the Switch statements. I am aware that I am showing a lot of code, but I am unsure as to where the problem may actually be. I'm not sure if I just need to add "break" lines or if I need a new integer value to create a different random number to determine a different number. Note: I know the formatting is not necessarily correct with the brackets, but rest assured the brackets are there in the real code.

```
public String hm(char sex){
    if (sex == 'm') {
            r = i.nextInt(7);
                if (r == 0) {
                    n = i.nextInt(6);
                    switch (n) {
                        case 0:
                            f = "Aseir";
                        case 1:
                            f = "Bardeid";
                        case 2:
                            f = "Haseid";
                        case 3:
                            f = "Khemed";
                        case 4:
                            f = "Mehmen";
                        case 5:
                            f = "Sudeimen";
                        case 6:
                            f = "Zasheir";
                    }
                    n = i.nextInt(6);
                    switch (n) {
                        case 0:
                            l = "Basha";
                        case 1:
                            l = "Dumein";
                        case 2:
                            l = "Jassan";
                        case 3:
                            l = "Khalid";
                        case 4:
                            l = "Mostana";
                        case 5:
                            l = "Pashar";
                        case 6:
                            l = "Rein";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: you are missing `break;`

Comment: Review the JavaDoc for nextInt: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-.  nextInt(n) returns a random integer in the interval [0, n-1].  So for nextInt(6), the number 6 is never returned.  You will want nextInt(7) so your receive a random integer in the interval [0, 6].

Answer (score 2):

You missed break statement. It should be like this -

```
 switch (n) {
                    case 0:
                        f = "Aseir";break;
                    case 1:
                        f = "Bardeid";break;
                    case 2:
                        f = "Haseid";break;
                    case 3:
                        f = "Khemed";break;
                    case 4:
                        f = "Mehmen";break;
                    case 5:
                        f = "Sudeimen";break;
                    case 6:
                        f = "Zasheir";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `switch` statement at all.

You could provide simple arrays/array lists and get the value from it:

```
static final String[] F_NAMES = {
    "Aseir", "Bardeid", "Haseid", "Khemed", "Mehmen", "Sudeimen", "Zasheir"
};

//...
n = i.nextInt(F_NAMES.length);
f = F_NAMES[n];
```

Similar approach should be applied to the other names for `l`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add `break` statements in every switch case. Otherwise the execution "falls through" and only the last value you assign stays.

In addition to that, `i.nextInt(6)` returns numbers up to 5, so the last case options are never triggered. You need `i.nextInt(7)` to generate numbers in the full range 0-6.